# Oracle table Delete Looping -

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, sql-delete

I have a thirty party tool that has their stored procedure to delete records from the Oracle Tables which takes below arguments to delete the data from it

```
DELETE_TABLE1 UserId, Begin_Date, End_date
```

I have control to give these arguments based on which their process deletes the data. But sometime the process fails due to UNDO space error because based on the provided argument the data to delete may pile up to 10 Million or more than that.

The third party team says they can't update the stored procedures rather they are requesting to control the argument so only limited number of records are put in.

Is there a way i can control the values that can be passed as a argument  say limiting the rows to 50,000 and then pass them as a argument to the final stored procedure? And loop them in iteration?

I have an option to use Shell Script as well to call the third party stored procedure

Comment: Only if you can query the data to get a smaller date range that is a subset of what you really want to remove, that fits into your arbitrary limit. It isn't clear if you have that visibility.  Sounds like it's the third-party's problem though, to size undo properly, split the range up themselves, or validate the range you're allowed to pass - in roughly decreasing order of appropriateness, but YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

To `LIMIT` the number of rows to be `DELETED`, you must have to modify the procedure where the `DELETE` statement is executed.

It is a bad idea to delete rows in a loop. A `FOR LOOP`, is `ROW-BY-ROW aka SLOW-BY-SLOW`. So, either do it at one go using simple `SQL`, if not, then use `FORALL` to avoid the `LOOP` and do it in `BULK`.

Regarding limiting the rows, you could use `ROWNUM` each time you delete a set of rows, commit the transaction, release the `UNDO` and delete the next set of rows.

Since you are using `PL/SQL`, the best way is to use `FORALL` with a `LIMIT` in `BULK COLLECT`.

For example :

```
OPEN c_data;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_data
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab LIMIT 1000; -- Here you limit the number of rows to be processed
    EXIT WHEN l_tab.count = 0;
  END LOOP;
CLOSE c_data;
```